# Does ImageDataGenerator Class in Tensorflow Create New Data?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I know for a fact that many use the ImageDataGenerator class in Tensorflow for augmentation. 
I wonder if ImageDataGenerator creates new data with augmentation or applies random augmentation to the data and imports without duplicating and augmenting. Is there any way to create new data with augmentation if the latter is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augmentation is different from dataset enrichment.

Augmentation refers to creating new samples at runtime (they do not physically exist on your storage) in order to ensure the creation of a more robust model, avoid overfitting etc.

If you wanted to create different examples of your images, you have to manually iterate through your dataset, apply some image transformations, and save them to disk. Otherwise, a picture rotated by 20 degrees for instance to left will be present only at training time for the network but not persisted to your disk.